# SMTP sends email using codeigniter in localhost but not on web hosting

Tags: php, smtp, fsockopen

I have managed to get my sendmail function to work in my local host however when i upload it to my webhosting I am presented with a long list of errors. I am using gmail and it works fine locally. I am thinking it is something to do with the SSL. Here are my errors a recieve:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846
```

This list goes on and on. Here is my function which sends the email and the config array used:

```
            $config = array(
                'protocol' => "smtp",
                'smtp_host' => "smtp.gmail.com",
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => "removed",
                'smtp_pass' => "removed",
                'mailtype'  => "html",
                'charset'   => "iso-8859-1"
            );


            //generate a random key
            $key = md5(uniqid());

            //load email library and set config settings
            $this->load->library("email", $config);//array("mailtype"=>"html")
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->load->model("model_users");
            $this->email->initialize($config);
```

My hosting is with 123-reg.co.uk and i'm thinking it is something to do with the SSL. any help would be great thankyou.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is, i'm trying to send an email with php in codeigniter, it works but not on my webhost. I'm sure it is to do with the fsockopen() error. something on the hosting is stopping the email from sending as it sends fine with local host.

Comment: @Louis, got any solution for this? facing the same issue.